# Testcafe - Unable to upload files with input type="url" which is a react custom made file upload component

Tags: testing, automated-tests, devexpress, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to upload a file but getting error "**The specified selector does not match a file input element**", I know testcafe requires input type="file" for uploading files, But as we are reusing our custom component for file uploads where we are giving input type="url" It's not working with testcafe.

Here is the java script/HTML code

```
<input name="images" accept="image/*" type="url" class="form-control col-11 false" value="">
```

And I am trying to access the css selector like this

```
const click_add_image=Selector('input[name="images"]')
const add_image=Selector('input[name="images"],input[inputtype="url"]')

test
    ('add images', async t=>{
        await t
            .click(click_add_image)
            .wait(2000)
           .setFilesToUpload(add_image,[
           './_uploads_/Share_Knowledge.png'
            ])
```

I am getting error  **The specified selector does not match a file input element**

Comment: The t.setFilesToUpload action works only with `input type="file"`. Are you sure that there are no such inputs? You can try to search for them by the following selector: `Selector('input[type="file"]')`. If so, you can try to implement your own uploading mechanism for your custom component using  ClientFunction. If you face issues with it, please describe how this upload component works or share a simple project. We'll try to find a suitable solution.

Comment: @DmitryOstashev Thanks I solved it, I am accessing currently like this,
 const add_image=Selector('input[name="images"],input[accept="image/*"]') This worked for me.

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).

Comment: @mlosev thanks buddy, anyways its solved now.